# Laravel Regex Validation does not work

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I want to define the username as **4 letters + 4 digits** like "`abcd1234`". Here is my code in Laravel 5:

```
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'username' => 'required|regex:/^[A-Za-z]{4}\d{4}$/|unique:users',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:8'
        ];
    }
```

However, the regex validation does not work at all. How to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: can letters and digits be in any order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is correct. The problem is that `use App\Http\Requests\Request;` is missed in the `RegisterRequest.php`.

The statements in the `RegisterRequest.php` should like this :

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Requests\Auth;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class RegisterRequest extends Request {

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'username' => 'required|regex:/^[A-Za-z]{4}\d{4}$/|unique:users',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:8|confirmed',
        ];
    }

}
```

Finally,`'username' => 'required|regex:/^[A-Za-z]{4}\d{4}$/|unique:users'` works very well !

Answer (score 0):

From [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-regex)

> **regex:pattern**
>
> The field under validation must match the given regular expression.
>
> Note: When using the regex pattern, it may be necessary to specify
>   rules in an array instead of using pipe delimiters, especially if the
>   regular expression contains a pipe character.

So, You should do something like this

```
$rules = array('form_field' => array('required', 'regex:foo'));
```

Comment: @rock321987 may be coincidence .

Comment: I have tried `'username' => array('required', 'regex:/^[A-Za-z]{4}\d{4}$/')`. But it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
[a-zA-Z]{4}\d{4}
```

`[a-zA-Z]{4}` means 4 letters `\d{4}` means 4 digits

Comment: Who is asking for meaning?